# Composition vs inheritance. Where did I go wrong?

Tags: c#, oop, composition

I need to model organizational hierarchy structure in my entities. An organization can be head-office, regional head, sub region, area office. There are a lot of common functions that the organizations are performing, but there are several functions that are specific for example only Regions can perform task A. There is also some properties(data) that is specific to Region.

I modeled it using composition and not using inheritance, but now I have ended with only a single organization class, with lot of references which depending on the TYPE of organization can have valid references or be null.

Object composition was a pain which now I am handling through factories. But now my main concern is the developers need to remember what the organization type is and whether a property has some meaning for that organization or not.

Just to be clear what I mean.

```
    public class Organization : IKeyed<int> {
        public virtual int Id { get; protected set; }
        public virtual string Code { get; set; }
        public virtual OrganizationType orgType {get;set;}
        public virtual Organization Parent {get;set;}
        public virtual IList<Organization> Children {get;set;}

        public virtual typeA {get; set;} // only meaningful when organization type is 'Head office'

        public virtual typeB {get;set;}// only meaningful when 'Region'
        public virtual void AddChild(Organization org){...}
    ...

    }
```

Should I have used inheritance over here? Or am I missing some tricks here?

Comment: probably it could have been more comfortable and convinient to have  a hierarchy and not have the TypeA/TypeB as base class properties. I dont see a composition here.. can any organization contain other organizations? Even if so, still probably having TypeA and TypeB at relevant classes will be easier to use

Comment: For brevity i have simplified it a lot and forgot to mention the fact, that each organization also has a reference to Parent, and its children organizations.

Comment: @YavgenyP TypeA and typeB are reference to properties that are only useful if the type of the organization is say Headoffice.. There would be a lot of other references that are only valid if Type is say Region... and so on

Comment: So i dont see a better solution that creating a hierarchy of classes by using inheritance..

Comment: Hmmmn thanks @YavgenyP. I suspected that was the case. All those composition over inheritance talks have made things a lot difficult. :)

Comment: Hi @UmairAhmed. You absolutely need to use hierarchy, you need a base class (Where shared things exist) and two child classes (one for each TypeA and TypeB) then your code will be cleaner, more understandable, I suggest you read some OOP books to feel the Object Oriented Programming and be aware were to put what in classes, this way you can be a designer. Good luck my friend.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In my opinion, I suggest you create an abstract base class that hold common behaviors and fields. Then you can add sub-classes to extend more specific behavior and/or properties.

```
public abstract class Organization : IKeyed<int> { 
    public virtual int Id { get; protected set; } 
    public virtual string Code { get; set; }

    // remove this property
    // public virtual OrganizationType orgType {get;set;} 
    public virtual Organization Parent {get;set;} 
    public virtual IList<Organization> Children {get;set;} 

    // move this property to sub-class
    // public virtual typeA {get; set;} // only meaningful when organization type is 'Head office' 

    // move this property to sub-class
    // public virtual typeB {get;set;}// only meaningful when 'Region'

    public virtual void AddChild(Organization org){...} 
    ... 

}

public class HeadOffice : Organization
{
    public virtual typeA { get; set; }
}

public class Region : Organization
{
    public virtual typeB { get; set;}
}

public class OtherOrganizationType : Organization
{
    // 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In regards to your specific question inheritance vs. composition: The maxim i've heard over and over again is "use inheritance when object A is a type of object B. Use composition when object A is made up of object B".

In this case, you can't say that a regional office is a type of head office. Nor can you say that a head office is made up of regional offices. This tells me that the objects should not be directly related. Instead, think about what it is about each that makes them eligable to perform common tasks. Maybe they can both HireWorker because they are both HiringOrganizations, maybe they can both ReportSales because they are both SalesEntities. In these cases, you should have a HiringOrginization or SalesEntity superclass, of which both HeadOffice and RegionalOffice are subclasses.

As far as org structure goes, it might be worth considering to maintain that structure in a separate OrgStructure object. Instead of having a Parent attribute and a Child attribute in each object, your OrgStructure object would maintain the relationships between all of the object instances. This provides a bit more flexibility, and removes the responsibility of maintaining relationships into a dedicated object.